# Why is GitPython's stream_object_data not threadsafe?

Tags: python, git, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, gitpython

The [documentation](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.cmd.Git.stream_object_data) states:

> This method is not threadsafe, you need one independent Command instance per thread to be safe !

I looked through the code, and found no reason for it to be the case. I also found no other mention of the term "independent Command".

The only thing I can think of is that this method was added in [this commit](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/commit/8c1a87d11df666d308d14e4ae7ee0e9d614296b6), in a time when Python's `subprocess` wasn't threadsafe. But that would apply to all commands, not just "independent" ones...